# What is your opinion on SE Meta post regarding questions that cross Community lines?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, asking-questions, migration

Recently I have seen several questions that sit on the fence between staying in the Community and being Migrated because another Community might be able to better help.  I recently put a [proposal on SE Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297981/why-not-let-communities-refer-questions-to-other-communities) to provide another alternative - Community Referrals.

Personally I often don't like Migrating questions.  The OP usually posts the question where they posted it because that is the Community they felt it associates with.  Migrating it often means the Community (and sometimes the OP) loses. Rather than just Migrating questions, I feel a better to also provide a way to ask for help from other Communities.

What do you think?  Would it help our Community?

Answer (score 1):

I've mentioned this to others in the past as well, but in the form of sharing tags. Essentially any similarly named tags from this site could be provided almost as an Ad on, say, Arduino.SE if someone searches that site for a question or answer related to that tag.

For instance, if someone is searching for information on special pinouts available on the "MightyBoard" controller (which is similar to Arduino), then questions available on our site related to [mightyboard](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mightyboard) can show up amidst the regular search results.

This would negate the need for moderators or community members needing to individually refer posts to other sites and provide new sites the opportunity to bring more members in.